# Is Bifenthrin available for sale in Canada?

Tags: insects, pesticide, mosquito

I want to treat my backyard for mosquitoes and have seen Bifen I/T as a recommended brand in many articles. After searching for it, I realized I could not find any Bifenthrin products in Canada.

Am I missing something? what do pest control companies use then?

Comment: Mosquitos breed in still water.  Do you know where they are breeding ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is something newer, it is not for sale in Canada anymore.

> Date of Last Sale by Registrant: December 31, 2018
> Last Date of Sale by Retailers: December 31, 2019
> Last Date of Permitted Use by Users: December 31, 2020

From [Registration Decision RD2017-19, Bifenthrin and Capture 240 EC](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/consumer-product-safety/reports-publications/pesticides-pest-management/decisions-updates/registration-decision/2017/bifenthrin-capture-240-ec-2017-19.html)

---

Mosquitos breed in still water.  You can

1. Try and remove these areas (such as gutters and small ponds)
2. Empty or disturb the water (with a tiny solar-powered pump)

If that is not possible (for us they breed in the septic tank), then you can get a trap.  Note that most traps sold do not work.  In particular, mosquitos are not attracted to UV, IR, heat or colour.  They are attracted to scents.  After trying a variety of them I have found that Pestrol Terminator or Pestrol Dominator work.  They use a lure (which you have to keep buying) that supposedly smells like human sweat.

We know that these devices work, because when we notice the mosquitos in the house, we know that it's time to replace the lure.  Then they disappear for a few months.

**Declaration** - I am not affiliated with Pestrol in any shape or form.